# full height of a div inside a table

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to align the following div's to be always on same position width and height on any webpage? I have try anything but I cannot manage to get it working. Something is not compatible in my code.

```css
.content-box-gray .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  color: #3385FF;
}

.content-box-gray .title {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
  background: gray;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  display: block;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
        <div class="content-box-orange">
          <div class="titleorange">3</div>
          <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:100% ">
      <td style="background-color: aqua;height: 50%">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: aqua;height: 50%">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #FFF">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #FFF">5</td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <div class="content-box-gray">
          <div class="title">7</div>
          <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #FFF">6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/robertaccess/pfa3Ls69/#&togetherjs=EwamIGVg01)

I cannot manage to fix it.

here is a pic [alignment of divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZP48.jpg)

thank you very much!

Comment: Would you be open to using flexbox instead of a table layout?

Comment: You have used bootstrap ? @Robert Constantin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the `td` a `height` of `100%`. Then use the [calc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc) property to set the height of `.content-box-orange .content`

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/vdcga31f/1/)

I think that you could explore flexbox instead of table for this layout. Update your question if you are open to that...

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
  background-color: #E5E5E3
}

table tbody tr td {
  height: 100%;
}

.content-box-gray .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #3385FF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.content-box-gray .title {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  display: block;
  color: #464648;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.content-box-orange {
  height: 100%;
}

.content-box-orange .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #000;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  height: calc(100% - 66px);
}

.titleorange {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #F78D27;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">
        <div class="content-box-orange">
          <div class="titleorange">3</div>
          <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height:100% ">
      <td style="background-color: aqua;height: 50%">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: aqua;height: 50%">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #FFF">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #FFF">5</td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2">
        <div class="content-box-gray">
          <div class="title">7</div>
          <div class="content">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #FFF">6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

### **Using Flexbox**

Here is a rough guide to achieving the layout in your image using flexbox. Refer to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) for browser compatibility information. You can toggle properties in Chrome Dev tools to get an idea of how flexbox properties work if it's new to you.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pfa3Ls69/2/)

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #FFF;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

.box,
.main {
  border: 5px solid #43c2eb;
}

.title--orange {
  background: orange;
  text-align: center;
  padding: .4em;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 200px;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.box-wrap {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box {
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.box--big {
  flex: 2 1 auto;
}

.box--small {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.main {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 5px;
}

.content {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row upper">
    <div class="box box--big">
      <h1 class="title--orange">div header</h1>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-wrap">
      <div class="box box--small">
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <h2 class="title--orange">div header</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="box box--small">
        <div class="content">content</div>
        <h2 class="title--orange">div header</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row main">
    <div class="main__inner">content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row lower">
    <div class="box-wrap">
      <div class="box box--small">
        <div class="content">content</div>

      </div>
      <div class="box box--small">
        <div class="content">content</div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box box--big">
      <h1 class="title--orange">div header</h1>
      <div class="content">
        content
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you sir, div 3 works well but unfortunately  1 and 2 are not have same height and 7 it's not the same size with 3. Can you have a look please?

Comment: Are you open to changing the HTML? It would be simpler with flexbox

Comment: It also wouldn't work on most browser using flexbox @ovokuro

Comment: @HarryKitchener Flexbox support is quite good now. Older versions of IE might need some workarounds but it's very doable http://www.caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @ovokuro Whilst it's much more supported than it used to be. It mostly only works on the latest versions of browsers, give or take a few iterations. You can't expect all users to be on the latest version of Chrome, Firefox, etc. Many are still on the Chrome ver that had the blue tab bar. Can't remember the version number.

Comment: @HarryKitchener I've built websites with flexbox that need support for older browsers without major issues, that includes IE10. I take your point that it's not as widely supported as tables, which is why I asked OP if he was open to it...

Comment: Support to IE10 isn't impressive. Ideally, going back to IE8 is the way to go. But IE isn't the issue here, due to the small number of users on IE8. The main issue is that users on browsers, such as Chrome, are still on older versions and haven't updated. So whilst analytics might show that 70% of users are on chrome, for example, half of them might be on an outdated version that isn't supported by flexbox.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: So again, it depends on the OP's needs. Only they can answer that.

Comment: of course I want using the Flexbox but this is new to me and don't know where to start, and I already change from table to divs and back to table from the last hours...

Comment: @RobertConstantin Updated answer.

Comment: @ovokuro thankyou very much. works very well. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Remove style attributes and width,height attributes on your HTML code, no need it if you use CSS.

Also dont  use % on Width y if you want a static table.

```
<table width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
    <tr style="height:100% ">
    <td style="background-color: aqua;height: 50%">1</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `style="height:100%;overflow:hidden;"` to outer `div` and `style="height:100%;"` to `content` & `td`

```css
html,
body {
  height: 98%;
  background-color: #E5E5E3
}

.content-box-gray .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #3385FF;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.content-box-gray .title {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #F1F1F1;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  display: block;
  color: #464648;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.content-box-orange .content {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 0px;
  color: #000;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.titleorange {
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background: #F78D27;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana;
  display: block;
  color: #FFF;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 0px;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="3" style="height:100%;">





        <div class="content-box-orange" style="height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
          <div class="titleorange">3</div>
          <div class="content" style="height:100%;">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text</div>
        </div>



      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: aqua;height: 50px">1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: aqua;height: 50px">2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #FFF">4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #FFF">5</td>
      <td colspan="2" rowspan="2" style="height:100%;">
        <div class="content-box-gray" style="height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
          <div class="title">7</div>
          <div class="content" style="height:100%;">Lorem Ipsum</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="background-color: #FFF">6</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```